# showing result of one to one relationship result in view in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have one to one relation which is giving me my required result but i am unable to show result in my view.

this is my controller function

```
        public function showallProducts()
{    // parent table
    $productstock = Product::with('CurrentPrice')->get();
    return view('welcome', compact('productstock'));
}
```

my view

```
  <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>price</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($productstock as $value)
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        {{--<h4><a href="{{url('Job-Details',$show->id)}}">
              {{$show->jobTitle}}</a></h4>--}}

                        <p>{{ $value->id }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        <P>{{ $value->name }}</P>
                    </td>
                    <td><span>{{ $value->description }}</span>
                    </td>

                    <td><span>{{ $productstock->CurrentPrice->productprice 
           }}</span>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            @endforeach
        </table>
```

its giving me following error

```
 Property [CurrentPrice] does not exist on this collection instance
```

when i dd() in controller i get following result.

```
       Array
       (
             [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => effertz.org
        [description] => Williamson, Kozey and Marks
        [created_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:19
        [updated_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:19
        [current_price] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [product_id] => 1
                [productprice] => 52
                [created_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:21
                [updated_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:21
            )

        )

         [1] => Array
          (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => gulgowski.biz
        [description] => Schaefer, Simonis and Kiehn
        [created_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:19
        [updated_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:19
        [current_price] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [product_id] => 2
                [productprice] => 99
                [created_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:21
                [updated_at] => 2017-11-28 14:01:21
            )

    )
```

how i show result in view and what is the reason of above mentioned error as it seems good

Comment: use existance check like @if( ! empty($productstock->CurrentPrice)
    //
@endif

Comment: shows noting but i have result as i shows u in my controller through dd()

Comment: did you try currentprice instead of CurrentPrice?

Comment: yes i tried but not working

Comment: CurrenPrice is the function name defined in Parent model

Comment: I misread the dd, sorry, current_price is what its printing out as

Comment: not working i tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping using the loop: `foreach ($productstock as $value)`

so in your view you should work with `$value` instead of the whole collection `$productstock`.
Change your view: `{{ $productstock->CurrentPrice->productprice }}` to 
`{{ $value->CurrentPrice->productprice }}`

Comment: and changing CurrentPrice to current_price together with my answer

Comment: {{ $value->CurrentPrice['productprice'] }}